# Excel VBA select mulptiple cells based on selection

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

I would like to select multiple cells based on selection.

And here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Selection.EntireRow.Select

End Sub
```

I want to select the first four columns of rows in multiple cells, instead of the whole rows. How to achieve it?

[this is my Excel worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kGGV.png)
[image]

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Range(Range).Select`

Comment: I think you can try `RANGE(A:D).Select`. Reference is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.select

Comment: You can use a combination of [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) and [Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells). If you want to pick some particular range dynamically, you can use an [If-Then-Else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement) statement perhaps nested in a [For-Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) cycle or [...]

Comment: [...] [For Each-Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) cycle and check every [Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) property of every given cell. Try to avoid using Select (unless you objective is to actually select something, of course). Another property you might be interested in is [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize). `Selection.Resize(1,4).Select` might be what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Select Rows of Non-Contiguous Range

- Copy the codes into a standard module e.g. `Module1`.
- In your command button click event use either of the procedure names in the following way:

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      selectRowsOfListObject
  End Sub
  ```

  or

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      selectRowsOfFirstFourColumns
  End Sub
  ```
- The first procedure will select only the rows of the selected cells in the first (structured) table in the `ActiveSheet`. Any cells outside the data of the table (`DataBodyRange`) will be ignored.
- The second procedure will select all the row ranges of the selected cells in the first four columns, in the first four columns of the `ActiveSheet`. Any cells selected outside of the first four columns will be ignored
- Each or both of the codes can be used with command buttons on any worksheet when they will refer to the worksheet 'containing' the command button.
- If you want a command button on another worksheet to always refer to the first, you will rather have to create a reference to the first worksheet:
  Instead of

  ```
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  ```

  use e.g.

  ```
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  ```
- To better understand the differences, you could add another command button for the second code and then test each of them.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub selectRowsOfListObject()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    If Selection.Worksheet.Name = ws.Name Then
        If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = Intersect(Selection, tbl.DataBodyRange)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Intersect(rng.Rows.EntireRow, tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows)
            End If
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                rng.Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub selectRowsOfFirstFourColumns()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If Selection.Worksheet.Name = ws.Name Then
        If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = Intersect(Selection.Rows.EntireRow, _
                                ws.Columns(1).Resize(, 4))
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                rng.Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Rows_Selection()

Dim rng As Range
Dim active_cells_adress, row_no As Variant
Dim final_selection_adress As String
Dim rng1 As String
Dim i As Integer
Selection.EntireRow.Select

Set rng = Selection
rng1 = rng.Address


final_selection_adress = ""
active_cells_adress = Split(rng1, "$")
For i = 2 To UBound(active_cells_adress)
  row_no = Split(active_cells_adress(i), ",")
  final_selection_adress = final_selection_adress + "A" & row_no(0) & ": D" & row_no(0) + ","
  i = i + 1
Next

final_selection_adress = Left(final_selection_adress, Len(final_selection_adress) - 1)
Range(final_selection_adress).Select


End Sub
```

Comment: If the selected *cell* is `B2`, it will select `B2:D2` instead of `A2:D2`. If the selected *cells* are `B2`, `C4` and `A6` it will select `B2:D2` instead of `A2:D2`, `A4:D4` and `A6:D6`.

Comment: Exactly, what you have said is right. As per the screenshot, I was thinking first cell of the row is selecting. I have changed my answer now

Comment: Wow, not bad. If you would use `Option Explicit` which would force you to dim all variables: `Dim j As String`, `Dim i As Long`, `Dim rng1 As String`. `Dim n As Variant` and use better variable names especially for the strings, it would be great. Anyway, +1. Well done. You could also do `Set rng = Selection.EntireRow` and remove `Selection.EntireRow.Select`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) how to avoid `Select`. Of course, you cannot avoid it in the last line.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code including your suggestions.